# nodejs - separate array with value difference greater than 2

Tags: arrays, node.js

Is it possible separate array with value difference greater than 2

```
[
  '6',   '7',   '8',   '9',   '10',  '11',  '12',  '13',  '14',
  '15',  '16',  '31',  '32',  '33',  '34',  '35',  '36',  '37',
]
```

i want to separate like this

```
 [ '6',   '7',   '8',   '9',   '10',  '11',  '12',  '13',  '14', '15',  '16']
 [ '31',  '32',  '33',  '34',  '35',  '36',  '37']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < lowIndex.length; i++) {
        if ((lowIndex[i + 1] - lowIndex[i]) > 2)
            lowAnomaly.push(lowIndex[i]);
    }

Comment: array index value like arr[0]=10 and arr[1]=20 => true

Comment: yes always sorted

Comment: yes like 1,2,3,5,6,7,10,11,23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```js
"use strict";
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
function detectAnomalies(array) {
    const results = [];
    let lastValue = null;
    let currentSeries = [];
    
    for (const currentValue of array) {
        if (lastValue === null) {
            lastValue = currentValue;
        }
        
        if (Math.abs(currentValue - lastValue) >= 2) {
            results.push(currentSeries);
            currentSeries = [];
        }
        currentSeries.push(currentValue);
        lastValue = currentValue;
    }
    results.push(currentSeries);
    return results;
}

console.log(detectAnomalies(array));
```

Also, it is always nice to show what you have tried :)